# $\frac{(10!)!}{(10!)^{9!}}$ is an integer

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

I have to find a combinatorial proof to prove that

$$k=\frac{(10!)!}{(10!)^{9!}}$$

is an integer number.

I really don't know where to start from. I thought that another way of saying it might help more: prove that $(10!)! \pmod {(10!)^{9!}} \equiv 0$.

Comment: Easier to prove the more general result that $$\frac{(mn)!}{(m!)^n}$$ is a whole numbers, so you don't have all those horrible factorials of factorials. Then $m=10$ and $n=9!$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a multinomial coefficient :

$$k=\binom{10!}{10 , 10 ,\ldots ,10}=\frac{(10!)!}{(10!)^{9!}}$$ with $9!$ tens .

This is obviously an integer .

Comment: Let's say that if you know beforehand that the multinomial coefficient is an integer, then it's obvious :) But how do you prove it?

Comment: It represents the number of ways to partition $10!$ objects in groups of ten objects each .

Comment: Right! Add a proof of that and it's perfect. (like in the linked duplicate answer, for instance) :-)